# .htaccess pretty URL trouble

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been working on a .htaccess file to create some pretty URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This is the code that I'm using. Right now if i type www.example.com/test it behaves like www.example.com/index.php?key=test but the problem is when I enter www.example.com/test-2 it doesn't behave like www.example.com/index.php?key=test-2 rather search for a test-2.php file. How can I fix this? I want it to be able to redirect keys with "-" aswell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a minus to the character class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was adding a "-" character to .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Hope it helps you aswell :).

Thanks to Mario and Eric